# log tag option ignored by docker daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I do have a docker.conf drop in on Ubuntu 16.04 for system.d that looks like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 --log-driver syslog --log-opt tag='docker/{{.Name}}'
```

I expected the tag in var/log/syslog to look like docker/ but it still is using {{.Name}}/{{.ID}}

Is there anything else I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from the documentation, but log tag configuration for a container is generated when the container is built.

If you rebuild your container(s), then you should see logging tagged with the new tags.

This was the case for me with `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`.

The clue leading me to this discovery was from https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags/:

> If you use docker rename to rename a container,
>   the new name is not reflected in the log messages. Instead, these
>   messages continue to use the original container name.

However, if you're using docker-compose, then setting the tags option under logging options takes effect when the container is restarted:

E.g.

```
services:
  nginx:
    logging:
      options:
        tag: "docker/{{.Name}}"
```